# How can I remove values from my Parent Grouping?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to categorize questions as yes/no, but i dont want the values to show up on the parent row. Only the users row.

Is it best to setup a hierarchy on one table? Im still new to PowerBI. I want it structured liked the 1st screenshot.
[EXCEL]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MztVg.png
[POWERBI]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugAI2.png

Answer (score 1):

You can try with measure. DAX has function HASONEVALUE.

```
MeasureToTry =
 if (hasonevalue(Table[Column]), 1, BLANK() )
```

Replace 1 depending on your logic.

Comment: Thank you, can I enter this formula on a current column or do I need to create a calculated column/measure?

Comment: try as new measure